# Permutation count for sets with multiplicities

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I am able to do a permutation counr for the set `{a, a, b}` which gives me 3 groups. I am happy with that result. However, if the set is `{a, a, b, c, c, d}`,  *Mathematica* gives me all the possible groups, but it is difficult to count the number of groups. Can *Mathematica* find the total number of groups? If so, which function to do I use?

Comment: I must be missing the question. But isn't the length of the list the same as number of groups?  Length@Permutations[{a, a, b, c, c, d}] gives 180. Or you looking for some other number?

Comment: @Nasser I agree that is unclear how the word 'group' is to be interpreted. The first answer counted permutations. I merely presented another approach for that objective. OP will presumably clarify.

Answer (score 8):

You can count the permutations using `Multinomial`:

```
cp[u_List]:=Multinomial@@(Tally[u][[All,2]])
```

Testing:

```
test={{a,a,b},{a,a,b,c,c,d},{a,b,d}}
cp/@test
```

yields:

{3, 180, 6}

Answer (score 6):

`Length@Permutations[...]` certainly suffices but for larger multisets I would just define a function that does not find all the permutations and instead uses the explicit formula if the number of permutations is all that is of interest.

```
PermutationCount[list_List] := 
 With[{len = Length@list, dups = Length /@ Gather[list]}, 
  len!/Times @@ Factorial /@ dups]
PermutationCount[{a, a, b}]
(* 3 *)
PermutationCount[{a, a, b, c, c, d}]
(* 180 *)
PermutationCount[{a, b, c}]
(* 6 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case that you want partial permutations (k-permutations) you will need something more than [`Multinomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Multinomial.html).  For that I suggest this function:

```
kP =
  SeriesCoefficient[
    #2! Product[Sum[\[FormalX]^r/r!, {r, 0, n}], {n, #}],
    {\[FormalX], 0, #2}
  ] &
```

Which can be formatted in the FrontEnd like this:

[image]

Example of use:

```
lst = {"a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d"};

kP[Last /@ Tally[lst], 4]
```

> ```
> 102
> ```

Confirmation:

```
Permutations[lst, {4}] // Length
```

> ```
> 102
> ```

It can handle large sets:

```
SeedRandom[1];
lst = RandomInteger[500, 2500];

kP[Last /@ Tally[lst], 75]
```

> ```
> 14234989704140257941300312514179784876937595388745791760303140394396200500917930350000721682369301114491055047302455106937589189933917947645440365920659637314061106826442544855655885539058290509408064000
> ```