# How to model rolling a pair of dice 100 times (Monte Carlo)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, simulation

Like the title says, I'm having trouble trying to write out a function that will find the probability of finding the sum of a pair of dice 100 times to find the probability of each sum of 2,3,4,5...up to 12.

I've started with

```
counter[n_][0] = 0; n = 100;
Table[{x[i] = Random[Integer, {1, 6}], y[i] = Random[Integer, {1, 6}]
```

but I'm not sure how to write the If statement part in which the counter will add 1 for every-time the sum of `x[i]`+`y[i]`=2,3,4,5, or 6.

Comment: `Tally` is the function you're looking for

Comment: Also your `Table` statement doesn't seem complete.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34861).

Comment: What is the relevance of the 100 times?  Are you seeking a sampling distribution of some statistic that depends on the sample size?

Comment: @Wolfies - It's just an example of the Monte Carlo problem by taking many samples and estimating the distribution by the 100 samples. Obviously the bigger the sample size the closer we get to the real distribution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In *Mathematica* it is natural to approach such a task with list operations and pattern matching.

```
dice1 = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 100];
dice2 = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 100];
Count[dice1 + dice2, 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6]
```

You seem to be a very new beginner, since you are using `x[i]` and `y[i]` as if these are vectors, when they are in fact not, in *Mathematica*. *Mathematica* is very different from other softwares, like *MATLAB*, so you can't just jump right into it without reading a tutorial first. Nevertheless, here is another solution:

```
Total@Boole[2 <= Total[#] <= 6 & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {100, 2}]]
```

Comment: I'm taking a math modeling class, and my teacher recommended doing it that method since most people in my class have never touched mathematica before. I've taken a basic course on mathematica, but it only included simple stuff.

Comment: Oh also, I forgot to mention that this problem was supposed to be a simulation of the Monte Carlo problem, instead using dice. This was perfect so thanks!

Comment: It may be a matter of taste, but I do find `With[ { dist = 
   EmpiricalDistribution @
    Map[Total] @
     RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], {100, 2}] }, 
 Probability[ 2 <= x <= 6, x \[Distributed] dist] ]` more general and easier to understand.

Comment: ... following this I would also consider the use of general statistical functions like `RandomVariate` and `EmpiricalDistribution` and `Probability` the more *natural* approach in *Mathematica* given what it is? (cf. my answer)

Comment: @gwr Your answer is very nice (you certainly have my vote), although I don't think the OP is trying to learn the probability functions in *Mathematica*. The way I interpreted the question he is just trying to learn basic *Mathematica* skills, and I chose my approach based on that.

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways you can do this, e.g.

```
ri = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {100, 2}];
SortBy[Normal@GroupBy[ri, Total, Length@#/100. &], First]
```

yielding:

> {2 -> 0.01, 3 -> 0.05, 4 -> 0.11, 5 -> 0.08, 6 -> 0.13, 7 -> 0.12,   8
>   -> 0.17, 9 -> 0.14, 10 -> 0.11, 11 -> 0.07, 12 -> 0.01}

rules linking sum to frequency.

You can also exploit `DiscreteUniformDistribution` and `TransformedDistribution`, e.g.:

```
dis = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}];
td = TransformedDistribution[
   x + y, {x \[Distributed] dis, y \[Distributed] dis}];
```

You can sample from `td`, e.g. `RandomVariate[td, 100]` and play with.

You can get probability mass function:  `PDF[td, x]`:

[image]

and finally just for fun (with polynomials):

```
func[k_Integer] := Module[{x = Unique[], rules},
  rules = CoefficientRules[Sum[x^j, {j, 1, 6}]^2, x]; ({k} /. rules)/
   36]
pmf = ProbabilityDistribution[func[k], {k, 2, 12, 1}]
```

So,

```
Show[Histogram[RandomVariate[pmf, 10000], Automatic, "PDF"], 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[pmf, x], {x, 2, 12}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}]]
```

[image]

```
{#, PDF[pmf, #]} & /@ Range[2, 12] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"S", "P(X=S)"}}] &
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `CoefficientRules`.  Since you have an appreciation for such methods have you seen [(40344)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40344/121)?  It's my take on methods found on http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Feb/msg00226.html.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. I had not seen  and look forward to reading it. :)

Answer (score 8):

While the answers so far have covered a lot of ground already I have not seen `EmpiricalDistribution`. I would like to build upon this observation by providing a couple of general considerations that I have found to be useful when doing statistical experiments using *Mathematica*. What users of *Mathematica* may take for granted may surprise newcomers: You can stay very close to the true "programming language" of models which is *Mathematics*.

So while one may of course work with low level functions like `RandomInteger` or `Boole` or `Tally` or `Count` one misses the flexibility and generality of the statistical framework provided by *Mathematica* which is easily transferable to lots of other cases.

**Working with Probabilities and Distributions in Mathematica**

I have come to quite like the general way that working with [probabilities and distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProbabilityAndStatistics.html) is done in *Mathematica* and whenever possible I try to stay within that framework.

Oversimplifying a bit one might see four sources for a distribution and accordingly separate Mathematica-functions:

1. [Parametric Distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParametricStatisticalDistributions.html) corresponding to some idealized stochastic model (e.g. [`DiscreteUniformDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteUniformDistribution.html))
2. [Nonparametric Distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NonparametricStatisticalDistributions.html) with the most prominent example being that we have a sample from an experiment (e.g. [`EmipricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html))
3. [Formula Distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) where we use `ProbabilityDistribution` to generate a distribution from a known PDF or CDF
4. [Derived Distributions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedDistributions.html) where the distribution is the result of some transformation of random numbers whose distributions are given (e.g. [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)

*A nice thing to note about (3) is, that for `ProbabilityDistribution` proportionality suffices which is nice for Bayesian statistics as Mathematica will take care of normalization if given the option `Method -> "Normalize"`).*

**Advantages of Working with Distributions**

If one comes up with a distribution, everything from then on will be *standard*. Thus we can:

- [Calculate Moments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StatisticalMomentsAndGeneratingFunctions.html)
- [Use Distribution Related functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StatisticalDistributionFunctions.html) like PDF and CDF
- [Do Simulation Experiments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html)
- [Calculate Probabilities](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html)
- [Find Expectation Values](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html)

So let us look at the question at hand and see how this works.

**Finding a Derived Parametric Distribution for the Sum of Two Dice**

Given a standard experiment we can immediately provide a parametric distribution that discribes the true (unbiased) distribution asymptotically:

```
SeedRandom["REPEATABLE@151108"]; (* make everything repeatable *)
$PlotTheme = "Detailed";

distSingleThrowOneDie = DiscreteUniformDistribution[ {1, 6} ];
```

From this we can directly derive the parametric distribution for the event "Sum of two dice after a single throw":

```
distSumTwoDice = TransformedDistribution[
    x + y,
    {
        x \[Distributed] distSingleThrowOneDie,
        y \[Distributed] distSingleThrowOneDie
    }
];

plotTheoreticalPDF = DiscretePlot[
    Evaluate @ PDF[ distSumTwoDice, x ],
    { x, 1, 12 },
    ExtentSize -> 0.5,
    PlotMarkers -> "Point"
]
```

[image: plotTheoreticalPDF]

We can now nicely use this distribution for the sum of two dice to calculate probabilities:

```
N @ Probability[ 2 <= x <= 5, x \[Distributed] distSumTwoDice ]
```

> 0.277778

**Doing Monte Carlo Simulations for Throwing Two Dice**

We can use any distribution to sample from it using `RandomVariate`. So let us throw two dice one million times:

```
totalSample = With[
    {
        sampleSize = 1000000
    },

    (* model throwing dice, so that each die might be given its own \
       distribution if needed *)

    Transpose @ {
        RandomVariate[ distSingleThrowOneDie, sampleSize ],
        RandomVariate[ distSingleThrowOneDie, sampleSize ]
    }
 ];
```

We can now use this experiment to see how the empirical distribution of the sum of two dice changes with growing sample size:

```
Manipulate[
    Module[
        {
            partialSample,
            distEmpiricalSumOfTwoDice
        },
        (* take the first n results and calculate the Totals *)
        partialSample = Map[Total] @ totalSample[[ ;; n ]];
        distEmpiricalSumOfTwoDice = EmpiricalDistribution @ partialSample;

        (* compare the plots *)
        Show @ {
            plotTheoreticalPDF,
            DiscretePlot[
                Evaluate @ PDF[ distEmpiricalSumOfTwoDice, x ],
                {x, 2, 12 },
                PlotStyle -> Red,
                PlotRange -> {{ 1, 13}, {0, 0.3} },
                PlotLegends -> None
            ]
        }
    ],
    {{ n, 10},{ 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 }}
]
```

[image: DiceExperiment]

Comment: The answer may be a bit overdone but I felt that some kind of general purpose guide to doing (simple) statistical experiments with Mathematica might be useful - and the question nicely fits as an example. Mathematica offers a very nice coherent framework for working with probability and statistics. Observe, for example, how the `PlotLegends` (automatically) show the probabilities for the events.

Comment: Nice answer and learning source for me, not overdone at all,

Comment: Prolly not something a novice will easily follow at first, but s/he should be aware *Mathematica* is capable at this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RandomVariate` to sample from a `DiscreteUniformDistribution` and then add up the pairs, calculate the probability of the sums observed, and then extract the probabilities of interest.

```
(#/100. & /@ 
     Counts[Plus @@@ 
       RandomVariate[
        DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], {100, 2}]]
)[#] & /@ Range[2, 6]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[x + y, {
    Distributed[x, 
        DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]], 
    Distributed[y, 
        DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]]}];

SeedRandom[1]
```

For small sample sizes, the match to the theoretical values is poor.

```
data = Total /@ RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {100, 2}];

Show[
 Histogram[data, {1.5, 12.5, 1}, "PDF",
  ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray]],
 DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, t], {t, 2, 12},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]

The match is good for very large sample sizes..

```
data = Total /@ RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {10000, 2}];

Show[
 Histogram[data, {1.5, 12.5, 1}, "PDF"],
 DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, t], {t, 2, 12}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for i dice with j faces using `IntegerPartitions` and `Permutations`.

```
dice = 2;
faces = 6;
range = Range[dice, dice*faces];

res1 = 
    Flatten[Permutations /@ #, 1] & /@ 
        (IntegerPartitions[#, {dice}, Range @ faces] & /@ range);

len = Length /@ res1;

pro1 = 1/faces^dice*len;

Grid @ Join[
      {{"Points", "Probability", "Casts", "n Casts"}},
      Transpose[{Range[dice, dice*faces], pro1, res1, len}]]
```

[image]

Now we cast the dice many times:

```
casts = RandomChoice[Flatten[#, 1] &@ res1, 200000];

pro2 = KeySort @ CountsBy[casts, Total]/200000.
```

> <|2 -> 0.027795, 3 -> 0.056105, 4 -> 0.08404, 5 -> 0.111665,   6 ->
>   0.138945, 7 -> 0.166145, 8 -> 0.137715, 9 -> 0.110435,   10 -> 0.0836, 11 -> 0.05546, 12 -> 0.028095|>

Does this agree with the formula result?

```
(pro1 - Values @ pro2) // Total
```

> -1.00614*10^-16

Almost!

Comment: A tiny English tip: "dice" is a plural noun, while "die" is singular.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that saves some additional bytes

Comment: Unfortunately "die" is also quite final - maybe not a good choice for repeating something ad infinitum... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(* Model an unbiased  six-sided dice throw *)

dice = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}];

(* generate random 2 N throws  and compute probabilities of sum *)

Sumdice[j_, num_] := 
 Count[RandomVariate[dice, {num, 2}], _?(Total[#] == j &)]/num

ListPlot[Table[{j, N[Sumdice[j, 10^5]]}, {j, 2, 12, 1}], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

In case you want the cumulative probability of getting two different sums (say j and j+2)

```
Sumdiceb[j_, num_] := 
 Count[RandomVariate[
    dice, {num, 2}], _?(Total[#] == j \[Or] Total[#] == j + 2 &)]/num

 ListPlot[Table[{j, N[Sumdiceb[j, 10^5]]}, {j, 2, 10, 1}], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]